# Passing Values from one class to another. Separate cpp files . C++

Tags: c++, allegro

I am struggling to pass values from one CPP class files to a seperate CPP file.

I have been trying loads of different operators to try and pass the values, I know I am missing something small, but I just cant think of anything else to do so I am here.

I am trying to pass the location `x_pos` and `y_pos` in the `player` class to my `bullet` class so the bullets are fired from the location of the player. I just cant pass the value to the bullet class, headers are included.

Some of it is commented out, at the moment I have it set to fire from the same location.

```
#include "bullet.h"
#include "player.h"

Bullet::Bullet()
{
    x_pos = 400;
    y_pos = 300;
    sprite = load_bitmap("bullet.bmp", 0);
}

Bullet::~Bullet()
{
    destroy_bitmap(sprite);
    destroy_sample(Music);
}

void Bullet::update()
{
    x_pos -= 0.5;
    y_pos -= 0.5;
    //Music = load_sample("shot.wav");
//  play_sample(Music,255,128,500,true);
    if(x_pos > SCREEN_W)
    {
        destroy_bitmap(sprite);
    }
    if(x_pos < 0)
    {
        destroy_bitmap(sprite);
    }
    if(y_pos > SCREEN_H)
    {
        destroy_bitmap(sprite);
    }
    if(y_pos < 0)
    {
        destroy_bitmap(sprite);
    }
}

void Bullet::draw(BITMAP* buff)
{
    //if(key[mouse_b&1])

        //   {

              masked_blit(sprite,buff,0,0,(x_pos),(y_pos),sprite->w,sprite->h);

             // y_pos --;

         //  }

}
//masked_blit(sprite,buff,0,0,(&player::getX),(&player::getY),sprite->w,sprite->h);


#include "player.h"
#include "bullet.h"

player::player()
{
    x_pos = 400;
    y_pos = 300;
    sprite = load_bitmap("player.bmp", 0);
    bulletSprite = load_bitmap("bullet.bmp", 0);
    spriteState = idle;



    rightWalk = 0;
    leftWalk = 0;
    upWalk = 0;
    downWalk = 0;
}

float player::getX()
{

    return x_pos;
}

float player::getY()
{
    return y_pos;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Edit header files included.

Bullet.h

```
#include "Headers.h"


class Bullet
{
private:
    //float x_pos, y_pos; // this is the initial x and y position variable for the bullet
    float angle;
    BITMAP *sprite; // this is the sprite variable  
    SAMPLE *Music;


public:
    Bullet::Bullet();
    ~Bullet();
    int x,y;
    int x_pos, y_pos; // this is the initial x and y position variable for the bullet
    void draw(BITMAP* buff);
    void update();
    float setX(float x);
    float setY(float y);
};

player.h

#include "Headers.h"


class player
{
private:

    //double rightX, leftX; // this is the initial x and y position variable for the player
    BITMAP *sprite; // this is the sprite variable
    BITMAP *bulletSprite; // this is the sprite variable
    // put enemy sprite here.
    enum state{idle, up, right,down,left}; // this holds the movement for the player
    state spriteState;

    int leftWalk;
    int rightWalk;
    int upWalk;
    int downWalk;



    double bullet_direction;
    double bulletDirection();

public:
    player();
    ~player();

    double radians;
    double aimAngle();

    float x_pos, y_pos; // this is the initial x and y position variable for the player

    void mouseAngle(BITMAP* bullets);
    void hit();
    void update(BITMAP* buff);
    void draw(BITMAP* buff);

    float getX();
    float getY();
};
```

Um i know i am doing something wrong. i have been playing around for the last hour. getting messages like.

error a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object

looking at peoples comments i don't think i have linked up the two CPP files or i have not set up the x position from the player coordinates.

At the moment in the game when i press the mouse button it fires from 300,400 and only this location.

i want to pass the players x and y values to the bullet so i can blit the bullets from the location of the player? can i not sent non static values? as i move around it will be changing. in my code i have a while loop always running so it will update the bullet location and player location.

thanks again.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly. Does the Bullet know of a Player? Are you getting an error..?

Comment: I would like to suggest renaming your player class to be capitalized Player.  Consistent naming conventions can help other types of errors like confusing classes and instances.

Answer (score 2):

**Constructor way**

The best way would be to pass it through `Bullet`'s constructor like this :

```
Bullet::Bullet(float x, float y)
  : x_pos(x), y_pox(y)
{
  sprite = load_bitmap("bullet.bmp", 0);
}
```

Use example :

```
Bullet bullet(player.getX(), player.getY()); // x_pos and y_pos are properly set
```

**Setters way**

If you really can't do this way, try using [setters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) :

```
// Modifies x_pos from outside.
Bullet::setX(float x)
{
  this->x_pos = x;
}

// Modifies y_pos from outside.
Bullet::setY(float y)
{
  this->y_pos = y;
}
```

Use example :

```
Bullet bullet;
bullet.setX(player.getX()); // x_pos is now properly set
bullet.setY(player.getY()); // y_pos is now properly set
```

Answer (score 1):

@Ninetainedo provides a good answer on how to get the data from player to bullet adequately.

EDIT: I found two Errors in your header files

First: I don't see any guards in your headers. Perhaps you chose not to copy/paste them.

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H_
#define PLAYER_H_

class player
{
    // insert stuff here
};

#endif /* PLAYER_H_ */
```

Second: Your Bullet Constructor definition shouldnt be qualified

```
class Bullet
{
public:
    Bullet::Bullet();
};
```

should be

```
class Bullet
{
public:
    Bullet();
};
```

After making these two fixes, I was able to compile your code with this main and get the following results.

```
player Mario;
Bullet BulletBill;

Mario.x_pos = 15.0;
Mario.y_pos = 25.0;

cout << "BulletBill (" << BulletBill.x_pos << "," << BulletBill.y_pos << ")" <<endl;

BulletBill.setX(Mario.getX());
BulletBill.setY(Mario.getY());

cout << "BulletBill (" << BulletBill.x_pos << "," << BulletBill.y_pos << ")" <<endl;
```

I would like to add that perhaps you could create a third object, "Firearm", that bridges the gap between player and bullet. The player "has-a" firearm, and the firearm has a factory method to create bullets using the position of the firearm in the constructor. The firearms position is linked to that of its owner via reference.

Bullet.h

```
Class Bullet
{
public:
    // -- Constructor
    Bullet (int x, int y) : x_pos(x), y_pos(y)
    {
        // Do other stuff here
    }

private:
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
};
```

Firearm.h

```
#include "bullet.h"

Class Firearm
{
public:
    // -- Constructor
    Firearm(const int& x, const int& y) : x_ref(x), y_ref(y)
    {
        // Do other stuff
    }

    // Create New Bullet Here
    Bullet Fire() const
    {
        return Bullet(x_ref, y_ref);
    }

private:
    const int& x_ref;
    const int& y_ref;   
};
```

Player.h

```
#include "bullet.h"
#include "firearm.h"

Class Player
{
public:
    Player(int x, int y) :  x_pos(x), y_pos(y)
    {
         // More constructor stuff here
    }

    void Update_Position()
    {
        // Update X_Pos and Y_Pos 
    }

    Bullet Pull_Trigger()
    {
        return gun.Fire();
    }

private:
    int x_pos;
    int y_pos;
    Firearm gun;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply's., i have been playing around with this for a hour or so and i cant seem to pass the values from the player.cpp file to the bullet.cpp file. error a nonstatic member reference must be relative to the specific object?

Comment: Could you provide more code? Show the header files you are using and the main example?

Comment: @Jerunh, you should add a little more code in the `Firearm` class because it currently won't be aware of `Player`'s position.

Comment: @Ninetainedo The x and y positions in `Firearm` are references, so this is already taken care of.

Comment: @AtlasC1 Oh sorry, I didn't notice ! =x